# Adding sine wave with different amplitude and different frequency

Tags: trigonometry

How to express the following equation into a sine wave equation ?

$$S(t) = 4 + 3 \sin 100 \pi t + 5 \sin 200 \pi t$$

I understand that, for the sine wave with same frequency and different amplitude,

I can use the formula

$$\sin (\omega t)+ A_{2}\sin (\omega t)=(A_{1}+A_{2})\sin (\omega t)$$

but how to add sine wave that has different frequency ?

Thanks!

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It depends what your goal is, but there is an identity $$\sin A + \sin B = 2\sin\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right).$$ However, it is **not possible** to write your sum of sines with different frequencies as a sine with a single frequency, i.e. in the form $A\sin\left(\omega t + \phi\right)$ for some constants $A,\omega,\phi$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Thanks!

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth:  that identity requires the two sine waves to have the same amplitude, which is not the case in the original question.

Comment: The 4 is a dc component, so it is neglected. By definition you can not describe two different sine waves as one!

Answer (score -1):

You can't add two sines of different frequencies.
This is a fundamental limit which much of math and physics takes advantage of.

Its also the basis of the [fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform).

To put it simply, sines of different frequencies are orthogonal.